# Save an image blob in a folder of my project

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-mvc

My application is for videos search, the user can make a search about a video; then he can watch it and suggest an image from this video(corresponding to a postion of the timeline) as a poster of the video but this image should before validated by the Administrator.So to do that i should save this image into a folder of my project (On the server) in order to be able to pass it to the Administrator.
Code to get an image from the video is triggered when the user clics on a postion of the timeline (the event is "seek" and the function listner is "seekListener")

My question is : how to convert a blob image to a reel image with name and extention, and save it in a folder of my project?
Note: I'm using projekktor as a player

```js
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Projekktor - simply mighty video</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    body { background-color: #fdfdfd; padding: 0 20px; color:#000; font: 13px/18px monospace; width: 800px;}
    a { color: #360; }
    h3 { padding-top: 20px; }
    </style>
 
    <!-- Load player theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/maccaco/projekktor.style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
 
    <!-- Load jquery -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
 
    <!-- load projekktor -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="projekktor-1.3.09.min.js"></script>
 
</head>
<body>
<div id="video">
<video class="projekktor" poster="http://www.projekktor.com/wp-content/manual/intro.png" title="This is Projekktor" width="640" height="385" controls id="player_a">
    <source src="media/intro.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
   </video>
</div>
 
<script type="text/javascript">
/*
This script is just an example and included to build up the "demo status panel".
For daily practice installing the player to your site is MUCH simpler and stright forward.
Please take a look at http://www.projekktor.com/docs/quickinstall
*/
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 
 
 
    /*********************************************************************
    Some player event listeners to set general status information:
    *********************************************************************/
 
       var seekListener=function(Obj) {    
   $('#mouseclick').html(myPlayer.getPosition());
   //$('#mouseclick').html(myPlayer.getItem(current))
   //$('#mouseclick').html(myPlayer.getMediaType())
//alert(myPlayer.getItemMedia())
   //alert(projekktor('video').getPosition())
    //$('#time').text()
    // 1. Obtenir une référence sur l’élément <video>
var player = document.querySelector('#player_a video');
 
// 2. Créer un canevas aux dimensions de la vidéo
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.width = player.videoWidth;
canvas.height = player.videoHeight;
 
// 3. Obtenir le contexte de dessin du canevas
var cx = canvas.getContext('2d');
 
// 4. Capturer l’image actuelle de la vidéo
cx.drawImage(player, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
 
// 5. Convertir l’image capturée en fichier, et créer un lien vers ce fichier
 
canvas.toBlob(function (blob) {
  var a = document.createElement('a');
  a.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  a.target = '_blank';
  a.textContent = 'Voir l’image capturée';
  document.getElementById('mouseclick').appendChild(a);
});
 
    }
 
 
    /*********************************************************************
      Configure and instantiate the player and
      apply an "onReady" callback function
    *********************************************************************/    
    var myPlayer = projekktor('#player_a', {
    debug: false,
    playerFlashMP4: 'http://www.projekktor.com/wp-content/manual/jarisplayer.swf',
    playerFlashMP3: 'http://www.projekktor.com/wp-content/manual/jarisplayer.swf',    
    plugin_display: {
           logoImage: "yourlogo.png"
    }, controls: true,
    addplugins: ['controlbar']
    }, function(player) {
 
    // add listeners
    player.addListener('seek', seekListener);
 
 
 
    });    
 
});
</script>
<div id="panel">
    <ul class="info">
 
    <li>Mouse click <span id="mouseclick" ></span></li>
 
    </ul>
 
 
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe you should send it through ajax to a PHP script which would save it on the hard drive? It's pretty easy in PHP. On the JS side - you would have to create a FormData object in which you would store the BLOB. Then you'd have to use JQuery's $.ajax function with parameters processData: false and contentType: false in order to pass the form to the PHP script.

Comment: I have not a problem in sending my blob to my controller, but how  i can save this blob as an image in a folder ? (by the way i'm not using PHP, i use ASP.NET C#